# To which Singaporean building does the one in this still correspond?

Tags: tourism, yuri-on-ice

In the *Yuri!!! on Ice* end credits, we see a string of photos on social media featuring different characters. In one of them, Jean-Jacques Leroy is with some women in front of a Western-style building. The photo is tagged with #Singapore.

[image: Singapore still]

What location in Singapore does the building in this still correspond to? [Other stills](http://syncopatedid.tumblr.com/post/151434842548/yuri-on-ice-ed-instagram-posts) in the ED sequence without a "generic" background clearly have real-life counterparts, so it is likely that the same holds here. (The lion statue in one of Yuri Plisetsky's photos corresponds to [that at the exterior of the State Russian Museum](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photo-lion-statue-entrance-to-state-russian-museum-mikhailovsky-palace-st-petersburg-russia-image70182239), the building in Michele Crispino's photo to the [Florence Cathedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Cathedral#Fa.C3.A7ade), and the location in Otabek Altin's to the [Zhibek Zholy metro station](https://ak.picdn.net/offset/photos/55d7195f72375f2a29e590ed/large_w/offset_258205.jpg) in Kazakhstan.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this wikia page](http://yurionice.wikia.com/wiki/Jean_Jacques_Leroy) and evident by photographs, it is the [Raffles Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raffles_Hotel).

[image: Raffles Hotel]

Comment: Ah, I must have overlooked that when looking up the character's name somehow. Oh well.